# how to get a list of questions posted by followed users

Tags: python, django

Friends, I am trying to implement a question answer site in which a logged in user gets a list of questions and answers asked by the users he follows.
I am using django-friendship to implement user follows. I want to know how we can fetch all the questions posted by the users whom the current user follows.

I have tried the following but doesn't work.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.session.get('current_user'):
        questions = []
        users = Follow.objects.following(request.user)
        i = 0
        while i < len(users):
            posts = Question.objects.filter(user=users[i])
            questions.append(posts)
            i = i + 1
        return render(request, "welcome/index.html",locals())
```

Here's my template

welcome/index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for q in questions %}
       {{ q.title }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch all questions without looping

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.session.get('current_user'):
        users = Follow.objects.following(request.user)
        questions = Question.objects.filter(user__in=users)
        return render(request, "welcome/index.html",locals())
```

template

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for q in questions %}
       {{ q.title }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`posts` is a queryset. Thus, `questions` is a list of querysets and, in your template, you are not iterating over `Question` instances, but querysets that do NOT have a `title` attribute. You can try in your view:

```
questions.extend(posts)  # not: append
```

in order to obtain an actual `list` of `Question` instances. Or, you can change your template:

```
{% for qs in questions %}
    {% for q in qs %}
        {{ q.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```